# How to remove Empty Spaces and Dots in Text from Image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, captcha

I'm processing the images with OpenCV and Python. I need to remove the dots / noise from the image.
The Background and the Text,both have the empty Dots/ lines.
here is a example:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPbhz.jpg)
with this code i am able to remove the background

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)
_, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None,None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] #get CC_STAT_AREA component
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 50:   #filter small dotted regions
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png', res)
```

result is:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBcUM.jpg)

how can i fill the empty spaces in the text?
or
How can i make this image readable for OCR tesseract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work but you can try a dilate+erode and/or a erode+dilate transform.

See this image:
[image: image transformations: Open and Close]

This can be implemented with OpenCV:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Best Regards

Comment: thank you,  erode+dilate transform worked perfectly.